# Reactivate drag control fails in openlayers

Tags: vector, controls, openlayers, drag

all. I have this little Problem and i'am looking for some help:

first I have a function which contains the following:

```
var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(imageConfig.XPos, imageConfig.YPos);
var imageFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point);
layers.imageLayer.addFeatures([imageFeature]);
```

So a point is be drawn on the layer. On this layer there is also an openlayers drag control. It is activated after the point was drawn. Now I can drag the point around. Works like a charm.

This is a little part of a user driven step by step procedure. So after dragging is done the next steps doing something with the point. While these other steps the drag control is deactivated. In the procedure it is possible to jump between steps so the de/activate of the drag control is needed. This works fine.

At the end of all steps the point is removed from the layer. Also this works great.

BUT: if I call again the function which draws the point on the layer (of cause now it is a new one) and activate the drag control I cant drag the new point any more even if I try to select the point with mouse click?!

I controlled with firbug:

- feature is there
- feature is on the right layer
- control is there
- control is on the right layer
- control is activated

Maybe I' am missing a simple thing here. But I breaking my hed on this for two days now and can't find an answer.

By the way I found that in the first step sequence (when all works great) the controls feature property is set with the point feature. But in the second not. The same in the controls drag handler feature property.

I tried to set it manually by:

```
control.feature = imageFeature
```

and:

```
control.handler.drag.feature = imageFeature
```

I was looking for a function to set the new feature to the control. But can't find any on the openlayers docs.
Other controls at not active at the same time (controlled it with firebug).

But no luck. Didn't help. Why this? I'am sure that this should work. What am I doing wrong or miss under standing here???

Every help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by my self. Problem was that I used a geoext feature store to display points in a grid. This grid was configured wit a geoext feature selection model. I just copied this...
The selection model also asign a feature select control on the map. In the first round this do no conflicts to the drag control because it is loaded after.

When the the tool enters the first step again all controls are loaded to the map. the select control and the drag control is enabled. this can't be handled by open layers. It seems the last to map added control is the one which comes with priority. So you can enable the drag control after again and again. The select control wins.

The trick is to decativate the select control. Then all works perfect.